# SQL AVG AND JOIN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, average

I have the following task: Find the students with the average of grades greater than the average of all grades (All the grades of all the students are on the same column). Moreover I have to get from a different table his name.

**The first table looks like this:**

```
Student_ID   GRADE    Course_Name
50            10         Math
60             9         Math
100           10         Math
200            7         Math
50             8         Sport
100            7         Sport
```

and so on...

**And in the second table:**

```
Student_ID   Name
50           JHON
60           Mark
100          FIONA
200          ROBERT
```

I get my head tied up in the order of the things I should do. Can you help me with the sql oracle code and give me an explanation on how you thought in the process? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the thought process:

First, you need to realize that the names are not important for the task, you can just join them with the result of the average computation as last step. So focus on that one.

```
SELECT name, avg_grade 
FROM ( <query to get the averages> ) q 
JOIN students ON q.student_id = name_table.student_id
```

Second, Average of all grades is just one number, it can go in a subselect in a WHERE or HAVING condition. It also is just

```
SELECT AVG(grade) from grades
```

Third, you need the average grade of every student. This can be achieved with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT student_id, AVG(grade)
FROM grades 
GROUP BY student_id
```

Tying everything together:

```
SELECT name, avg_grade 
FROM ( 
  SELECT student_id, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
  FROM grades 
  GROUP BY student_id
  HAVING AVG(grade) > (SELECT AVG(grade) from grades)
) q 
JOIN students ON q.student_id = name_table.student_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is exactly what I was looking for. Your explanations have cleared my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT s.*, g.*,
        AVG(g.GRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Student_ID) avg_s,
        AVG(g.GRADE) OVER () avg_all
    FROM students s
    LEFT JOIN grades g
        ON s.student_ID = g.student_ID
) t
WHERE avg_s > avg_all
```

Edit:

If you just want to report each student alone who meets the grade criteria you may try doing `SELECT DISTINCT Name` in the outer select.

Comment: This code doesn't run on Oracle. You need to prefix the `*` in the inline query. Having fixed that the result contains a row for every line in the GRADES table, which is probably not that the OP wanted (although I agree they are not entirely clear about the desired output).

Comment: @APC I interpreted the problem that the OP wants all matching data, for each matching student.  If not, then we can try an aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is

```
select s.student_id, s.name, avg(g.grade)
from grades g
inner join students s on s.student_id = g.student_id
group by s.student_id, s.name
having avg(g.grade) > (select avg(grade) from grades)
```

Comment: The problem is first I need the Student AVG grades only for him, because as u see he have more grades at diferent courses only for him. So first I should get his average grade like Sport 9 Math 10 --> 9.5, and then compare it with the average of all the grades in the column that no longer keep track of sudent/course.

Comment: @Dummy Don't make a dummy out of us.  This answer is reasonable given the information you gave us.  If not, then show us sample output data.

Comment: Neither solution returns students whose **average grade** is greater than the overall average grade.

Comment: @APC you are right, I read the task incorrectly. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the average grade of each student join the two tables and GROUP BY the student ID and name. To get the average of all the grades you need a separate query, because it's a different qranularity. You can use this as a sub-query in the HAVING clause of the GROUP BY.

```
select g.student_id
       , s.name
       , avg(g.grade) as student_avg
from grades g
     join students s
         on g.student_id = s.student_id
group by g.student_id, s.name 
having avg(g.grade) > ( select avg(grade) from grades);
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c817/1).